# rails 6 Cannot find module 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

whats wrong there?

webpacker says:
Cannot find module 'jquery'

i have running multiple rails apps, but, now, do i not see my eyeglasses before my eyes?

[image]

**config/webpack/environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
);

const aliasConfig = {
    'jquery': 'jquery-ui-dist/external/jquery/jquery.js',
    'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
};
environment.config.set('resolve.alias', aliasConfig);

module.exports = environment
```

**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import 'foundation-sites';

//jquery and jquery-ui
require("jquery")
require("jquery-ui")

require("foundation");
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "passwords",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, my webpacker is running well.
differing from above, my settings are:

config/webpack/environment.js like above, but without the line "poper".

packs/application.js

```
// jquery and jquery-ui
require("jquery")
require("jquery-ui")
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = jQuery;
```

and: Webpacker is not running with current version of node! i am using `node -v 12.22.9` (for me the best was is managing node by nvm). yarn should be used at the current version.

jquery is installed by `yarn add jquery`

note:
now rails 7 will [come soon](https://rubyonrails.org/2021/9/15/Rails-7-0-alpha-1-released) and webpacker will no longer part of rails default package. currently its too early yet.